# Xamarin xaml using Idiom to bind image

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Hi I wanted to show different images in listview depending on the device type as shown below

```
    <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <local:Base64ToImageConverter x:Key="btoi"></local:Base64ToImageConverter>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>
 <ListView x:Name="lvImages"
              VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              SeparatorVisibility="Default"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"
              ItemSelected="lvImages_Selected"
              HasUnevenRows="True"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedImage}"
              IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
              CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
              RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}" 
              BackgroundColor="#009688"
              SeparatorColor="#FFFFFF"  >
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <!--<Image Source="{Binding PhoneImageData,Converter={StaticResource btoi}}" />-->
            <Image>
            <Image.Source>
              <Binding Converter="{StaticResource btoi}">
                <Path>
                  <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="String">
                    <OnIdiom.Phone>
                      PhoneImageData
                    </OnIdiom.Phone>
                    <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                      TabletImageData
                    </OnIdiom.Tablet>
                  </OnIdiom>
                </Path>
              </Binding>
            </Image.Source>
          </Image>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

but I am getting an error string not found in xamarin.forms.xaml please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `x:TypeArguments="x:String"` instead of `x:TypeArguments="String"`.

You need to specify a namespace for every type reference unless it exists in the default namespace context of the XML file. The default context is almost always `Xamarin.Forms.Xaml` because of the declaration on the root XML node of `xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"`, but `String` is in the `System` namespace. By default, the fundamental .NET data types (including String and others) are aliased in `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"`, which is why you need the `x:` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Set image source with device brands and type inside the xmal file:

```
<Image 
  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
  BackgroundColor="White"
  Aspect="AspectFit">

    <Image.Source>      
      <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="ImageSource">
          <OnIdiom.Phone>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ImageSource"
                          iOS="logo.png"
                          Android="logo.png"
                          WinPhone="logo.png" />
          </OnIdiom.Phone>
          <OnIdiom.Tablet>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ImageSource"
                          iOS="logo_iPad.png"
                          Android="logo.png"
                          WinPhone="logo.png" />
          </OnIdiom.Tablet>
      </OnIdiom>
    </Image.Source>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try (though I am not sure what you are trying to do with your `Binding` property:

```
<OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="ImageSource"
         Phone="PhoneImageData.png"
         Tablet="TabletImageData.png"/>
```

Edit: To make it better gel with your example:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <OnIdiom x:Key="image" 
                 x:TypeArguments="ImageSource"
                 Phone="PhoneImageData.png"
                 Tablet="TabletImageData.png"/>
   </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<Image Source="{StaticResource image}"/>
```

Edit #2:
Ok that makes more sense. Then I would suggest using the  `BindingContextChanged()` and then use the `Device.Idiom` check in that event subscription. You can use [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/73642/#Comment_73642) post to see how to do that. You can set your image binging to what ever, and then in `BindingContextChanged()` you can reset it to what ever base64 converted image you want.

If you run into problems let me know!

Comment: PhoneImageData or TabletImageData is a base64 string coming from database as a property in list item. So I have to use binding there.
The image is in the list